# Multitasking c#| Getting Array index out of bound

Tags: c#, task, indexoutofboundsexception

I’m writing a method which will download files from both LAN shared and FTP Shared directories. I have list of multiple vendors. I am using tasks to achieve this. But I am getting ArrayIndexOutofBond Exception. Although my loop condition is right?

Here is code segment.

```
 vendorWiseTasksListening = new List<Task>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < allVendorIDs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Task task = new Task(() => FTPMode(allVendorIDs[i]));
                        vendorWiseTasksListening.Add(task);
                        task.Start();
                        task = new Task(() => SharedMode(allVendorIDs[i]));
                        vendorWiseTasksListening.Add(task);
                        task.Start();
                    }
                    Task.WaitAll(vendorWiseTasksListening.ToArray());
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, unless your shared objects are made smart enough to be thread safe  ... they are not thread safe which means you get errors accessing them from multiple threads.

Comment: So how can i make sure that they become thread safe?

Comment: Locking of SOME sort. Programming in a way that does not require shared objects and does the collection at the end. LOCKING is easiest (read up the lock keyword). At the end: you ask us to teach you programming. Too broad.

Comment: Learn about thread safety. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623039/how-to-make-objects-threadsafe-on-c/11623449

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be, that the value of you variable `i` is NOT saved once you create the new task, but all your tasks use a reference to the same variable `i`. And this `i` is incremented until `allVendorIDs.Length`.

If some Task accesses the value of `i` after the loop in the main thread has finished, it will get `allVendorIDs.Length`.

Make a local copy of `i` and use this in your tasks:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < allVendorIDs.Length; i++)
                {
                    int j = i;
                    Task task = new Task(() => FTPMode(allVendorIDs[j]));
                    vendorWiseTasksListening.Add(task);

                    task.Start();
                    task = new Task(() => SharedMode(allVendorIDs[j]));
                    vendorWiseTasksListening.Add(task);
                    task.Start();
                }
```

See for example [this question for a simpler example and explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227820/why-is-it-bad-to-use-an-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression).